# how to create patch for changing cache size limits in sitecore config

Tags: configuration, caching, patch-configuration

Using `Sitecore 10.0.1`
I need to change the Prefetch and AccessResultCacheSize to 500 MB

The Prefetch cache size is set as below in one  config file

```
<prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
<sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Master.config" /></prefetch>
```

Inside the `Master.config` file, the below code is written

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><configuration<cacheSize>300MB</cacheSize </configuration>
```

And, AccessResultCacheSize  is set as below in `xyz.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 <settings>
<setting name="Caching.AccessResultCacheSize" s:value="50MB" /></settings></sitecore>
```

How to write patch file to change both above values to 500 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure Item and Data cache values, create a patch file for cache size values. For example, custom.caching.config and add the following

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="web" role:require="ContentDelivery or Standalone">
        <cacheSizes>
           <data>1000MB</data>
           <items>1000MB</items>
        </cacheSizes>
      </database>
      <database id="master" role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
        <cacheSizes>
            <data>1000MB</data>
            <items>1000MB</items>
        </cacheSizes>
       </database>
    </databases>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Caching.AccessResultCacheSize">
        <patch:attribute name="value">10000</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Refer to [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-item-and-data-cache-values.html) document for more details.

Add this patch for the prefetch cache size.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <caches>
      <cache name="prefetch">
        <param desc="Size (MB)">50MB</param>
      </cache>
    </caches>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @coder try the updated answer solution

Comment: The first solution you gave is working for id=master. But for id=web it throwing error "Could not find property 'dataProvider' on object of type: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerDataProvider
"

Comment: This is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below patch file to your project. The below patch file has a patch for Prefetch, Data, Item, HTML, and AccessResultCache values with respective Content Delivery and Content Management roles defined.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"
               xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <databases>
            <database id="master" role:require="ContentManagement or Standalone">
                <dataProviders>
                    <dataProvider>
                        <param desc="headProvider">
                            <dataProvider>
                                <prefetch>
                                    <cacheSize>1000MB</cacheSize>
                                </prefetch>
                            </dataProvider>
                        </param>
                    </dataProvider>
                </dataProviders>
                <cacheSizes hint="setting">
                    <data>1000MB</data>
                    <items>1000MB</items>
                </cacheSizes>
            </database>
            <database id="web" role:require="ContentDelivery or Standalone">
                <dataProviders>
                    <dataProvider>
                        <param desc="headProvider">
                            <dataProvider>
                                <prefetch>
                                    <cacheSize>1000MB</cacheSize>
                                </prefetch>
                            </dataProvider>
                        </param>
                    </dataProvider>
                </dataProviders>
                <cacheSizes hint="setting">
                    <data>1000MB</data>
                    <items>1000MB</items>
                </cacheSizes>
            </database>
        </databases>
        <sites role:require="ContentDelivery or Standalone">
            <site name="website" htmlCacheSize="200MB"/>
        </sites>
        <settings>
            <setting name="Caching.AccessResultCacheSize" value="200MB">
            </setting>
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

See the blog Post for more details: [Cache Tunning in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/09/cache-tunning-in-sitecore.html)